# Getting Data from Salesforce with Force.com sites page

Tags: force.com-sites, ajax

We have a requirement for a public facing page that requests data from SFDC without logging in.

So, the idea is for a public user to enter information, and based on that information, the page would interact with SFDC and return the data.

Perhaps, we would call SFDC via Ajax and REST and uses JS/DOM to display the data on the page.

Thank  you.

Comment: Why not just use a controller for the page to query for the data? Just make sure to set the appropriate permissions for the site guest user profile on the site settings.

Comment: Are you using Site.com or force.com sites?

Comment: TO sum it up. You want to integrate a external system in sfdc without authentication. Therefore the external system has to call a force.com site. The data is send from your external system to salesforce via force.com sites? Am I right?

Comment: To clarify, we will be using Force.com Sites (the one that comes with SF instance).

We need users to query for information in SFDC database, without logging in. At first we were gonna use Communities, but since there's no login, then we are exploring this possible solution.

The uncertainties are, can we use a controller page and return results like any other page in SF.

And, there will be very heavy traffic at certain points. This is a government type site, where citizens will query for information based on data they enter on a form.

Comment: You can use JavaScript remoting for pages served from Visualforce/Sites. Or you can create Invocable Actions that are accessible from REST API. With second one though, you will have to enable API access for public use, which means you will have to be very stringent how you manage the security, plus it counts towards API request limits per day.

Comment: [Here is somewhat related explanation about the differences among the two](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33661/when-to-use-apex-controller-vs-js-remoting-or-rest), although I think the top ranked question is too subjective.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Force.Com Sites will allow us to do this with reasonable limits:

Organization Type   Bandwidth Limit (per day)   Service Request Time (per day)
Developer Edition   500 MB                              10 minutes
Sandbox             1 GB                                30 minutes
Production          40 GB                               60 hours

Please let me know if you have conflicting information.

Thank you.